# how to determine between 2 mouse clicks of treeviews

Tags: c#, events, treeview

I have two treeviews and a contexmenucontainer with the adding node function
cmnuAddNode is the add tab of my contexmenuestrip
I'm a newbie working with events

I want to add the node to treeview 1 if clicked
and add the node to treeview2 if clicked
I just want to know what I should write in my if condition
my code is as below:

```
 private void cmnuAddNode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        NewNode n = new NewNode();
        n.ShowDialog();
        TreeNode nod = new TreeNode();
        nod.Name = n.NewNodeName.ToString();
        nod.Text = n.NewNodeText.ToString();

        n.Close();
      if (treeView1.SelectedNode!=null)
        {
            treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(nod);
            treeView1.SelectedNode.ExpandAll();
        }
        if (treeView2.SelectedNode!= null)
        {
            treeView2.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(nod);
            treeView2.SelectedNode.ExpandAll();
        }
          }
```

this code has exception when I click the treeview2

Comment: it can't have the input TreeViewEventArgs e1 because then it is not supposed to be a function event of the addclick event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple I got an index for my treeviews when it goes in treeview1 in event mouseclick of it I set it to 1 and when goes to 2 I set it to 2
so in my function add I wrote conditions this was simple and fast and easy

```
private void cmnuAddNode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        NewNode n = new NewNode();
        n.ShowDialog();
        TreeNode nod = new TreeNode();
        nod.Name = n.NewNodeName.ToString();
        nod.Text = n.NewNodeText.ToString();

        n.Close();

        if (treeviewindex== 1)
        {
            treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(nod);
            treeView1.SelectedNode.ExpandAll();

        }
        if (treeviewindex==2)
        {
            treeView2.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(nod);
            treeView2.SelectedNode.ExpandAll();
        }
        if (treeviewindex == 3)
        {
            treeView3.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(nod);
            treeView3.SelectedNode.ExpandAll();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void cmnuAddNode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e,TreeViewEventArgs e1)
{

    NewNode n = new NewNode();
    n.ShowDialog();
    TreeNode nod = new TreeNode();
    nod.Name = n.NewNodeName.ToString();
    nod.Text = n.NewNodeText.ToString();

    n.Close();
    if(e1.Node.TreeView == treeView1)
   {
    treeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(nod);
    treeView1.SelectedNode.ExpandAll();
    }
     if(e1.Node.TreeView == treeView2)
   {
    treeView2.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(nod);
    treeView2.SelectedNode.ExpandAll();
     }
}
```

Comment: you know why? bwcaue .treeview will get the parent

Comment: it is what i said contextmenu have to know context that is the parent . how contextmenu will send an treeview event from the good treeview try the first solution you will enjoy

Comment: if (e1.Node == treeView1.SelectedNode) this one doesn't work neither your below code is incorrect because cmnuAddNode doesn't have the parent it is context menue that has the parent and I corrected and tested and again no result

Comment: I know that it is for contextmenustrip, when i advise to try it, it is with a contextmenustrip of course

Answer (score 0):

first add a mouse click event for each TreeView
secondly select the correct node using the MouseEventArgs.
for treeview1 (do the same for treeview2)

```
    void treeView1MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            // Select the clicked node
            treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.GetNodeAt(e.X, e.Y);

            if(treeView1.SelectedNode != null)
            {
             cmnuAddNode.Show(treeView1, e.Location);
            }
        }
    }

//it will work for the two treeview getting Parent control of cmnuAddNode
private void cmnuAddNode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e,TreeViewEventArgs e1)
    {
        TreeView yourtreeView = (TreeView)cmnuAddNode.Parent;
        NewNode n = new NewNode();
        n.ShowDialog();
        TreeNode nod = new TreeNode();
        nod.Name = n.NewNodeName.ToString();
        nod.Text = n.NewNodeText.ToString();

        n.Close();

        yourtreeView.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(nod);
        yourtreeView.SelectedNode.ExpandAll();

    }
```

Comment: you didn't consider my contexmenue container

Comment: (TreeView)cmnuAddNode.Parent; why? I can't undestand and I can't understand why I can't just write 1 line instead of this?

Comment: because it allows you to get the control where you contextmenu is showed so if it is from treeview1 the parent of contextmenu is treeview1 if the contextmenu is showed from treeview2 parent control will be treeview2 (it explains work context)

Comment: it should have really a code to know if something is clicked then do something I have an event click which I wrote for my treeview I prefer not to change the whole.with mouse up I should clear my treeview click

Comment: cmnuadd  doesn't have show,something like contextMenuStrip1.SetBounds(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y, 23, 23);  is more better

Comment: can you tell me which control is cmnuadd exactly?

Comment: it is the tab of my context menue strip I have two tabs add and remove